# Write Past Value in data.txt

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write some list in data.txt.

The output from program is:

```
Triangle
('(a1, b1)', '(a2, b2)', '(a3, b3)')
Triangle
('(a4, b4)', '(a5, b5)', '(a6, b6)')
```

With this lines of code to write in data.txt;

```
data = {}
data['shapes'] = []
data['shapes'].append({
    'name': str(triangle.name),
    'Vertices': list(triangle.get_points())
```

I need output in my data.txt with json format like this:

```
{"shapes": [{"name": "Triangle", "Vertices": ["(a1, b1)", "(a2, b2)", "(a3, b3)"]}, {"name": "Triangle", "Vertices": ["(a4, b4)", "(a5, b5)", "(a6, b6)"]}]}
```

But this is what I get:

```
{"shapes": [{"name": "Triangle", "Vertices": ["(a4, b4)", "(a5, b5)", "(a6, b6)"]}]}
```

So, how can I write the past value of triangle that have vertices (a1, b1)...(a3, b3)?

Comment: Need to see how youre implementing this into your existing code because that would be where the error is. My guess is the data in `Triangle` is being overwritten before you add it to the dictionary, but without the code I have no way of telling.

Comment: Your current code only writes the data that is outputted last. ```"Triangle"``` is overwriting the values from the previous output and that is why your dictionary is storing only the latest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code should be executed **only once:**

```
data = {}
data['shapes'] = []
```

The following part of your code you should execute **repeatedly**

```
data['shapes'].append({
    'name': str(triangle.name),
    'Vertices': list(triangle.get_points())
```

probably in a loop similar to this one

```
for triangle in triangles:
    data['shapes'].append({
        'name': str(triangle.name),
        'Vertices': list(triangle.get_points())
```

Comment: Thank you @MarianD, your answer made my day. I put my code for write to data.txt in the same loop to produce triangle output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're overwriting the variable referencing the first triangle object with the next triangle object before appending the first triangle object's information to data['shapes'].

That block of code where you append to your data['shapes'] should be executed twice, once for each triangle object.